# Twice Nested Resource Form_For Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a double nested resource:

```
 resources :companies do 
    resources :orders do
      resources :comments
  end
 end
```

Am having issues when trying to include a form to create a comment in my orders show view. This is what I've tried:

```
<%= form_for([@order, @order.comments.build]) do |f| %>
```

However this gives me a no method error.

Any chance you can recommend the best way to deal with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define the company as well. If you write `rake routes` you can see that you dont have `order_comments_path` because its double nested, so you will se something like `company_order_commments_path` which takes minimum two parameters, a `company_id` and an `order_id`. So if you really want to use this 3 level nester resource you have to add a `@company` variable to the form path. Like:

```
<%= form_for([@company, @order, @order.comments.build] do |f| %>
```

But in the most cases it's useless to define both `company` and `order` to identify an `order`, so the other option which could be better to add separately another route for the `orders` and `comments`, and this makes sense.
In your routes.rb

```
...
resources :orders do
   resources :comments
end
...
```

So you can manipulate `orders`, without specifying the `company`. Also in the most general cases you don't get any important advantage by defining 3 level nested routes.